# How can I match four number fields or a text string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

So a sensor I'm interfacing to either outputs 4 multi-digit integers (separated by spaces) or an error string.

Ideally my regex would return a match for either of the above scenarios and reject any
other outputs - e.g. if only 3 numbers are output. I can then check if there are 4 groups (number output) or 1 group (error string output) in the following c#.

The regex I have matches all the time and returns spaces when there are less than 4 numbers so I still need to check everything.

I've tried putting in `?:` but the format breaks. Any regex whizzes up to the challenge? Thanks in advance.

```
([0-9]+\s)([0-9]+\s)([0-9]+\s)([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z\s_!]+)
```

So a numeric example would be `11 222 33 4444` or `Sensor is in an error state!` An incorrect output would be `222 11 3333` as it only has 3 fields

Also - I need to capture the four numbers (but not the spaces) or the error string.

Comment: Actual examples of what you're trying to match would probably be the most helpful.

Comment: What if you wrap this with anchors? `^(?:[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z\s_!]+)\z`? Or  `^(?:[0-9]+(?:\s[0-9]+){3}|[a-zA-Z\s_!]+)\z`?

Comment: The \s within the last brackets at the end doesn't seem right to me: [a-zA-Z\s_!]

Comment: Actually, the *error* pattern is not clear. Please clarify.

Comment: So a numeric example would be '11 222 33 4444'  or 'Sensor is in an error state!' An incorrect output would be 222 11 3333 as it only has 3 fields

Comment: Also - I need to capture the four numbers (but not the spaces) or the error string. Lavandysh - you're correct. that \s shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

You can capture either the 4 groups with only digits and match the whitespace chars outside of the group.

Or else match 1+ times any of the listed characters in the character class. Note that `\s` can also match a newline, and as the `\s` is in the character class the match can also consist of only spaces for example.

To match the whole string, you can add anchors.

```
^(?:([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)|[a-zA-Z\s_!]+)$
```

» [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u2sCKv/1)

Another option to match the error string, is to start matching word characters without digits, optionally repeated by a whitespace char and again word characters without digits.

```
^(?:([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)|[^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*!?)$
```

» [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7IPH6/1)

If there can be a digit in the error message, but you don't want to match only digits or whitespace chars, you can exclude that using a negative lookahead.

```
 ^(?:([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)|(?![\d\s]*$).+)$
```

» [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sk8glL/1)